# What are the performance differences using filter vs creating model functions

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models

I was wondering if there is any difference in performance between using filters in django template and formatting the output with functions in models?

Say you have the following model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name.title()
```

In the template I want to call the model and get the name with capitalized letters.

Which of these would be best (if any) concidering performance?

```
{{ example.name|title }}

{{ example.get_name }}
```

I guess it can't be a huge difference, but with tables showing hundreds of items, is there anything to gain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't care about the performance on this cause you won't gain much by using model methods. But if you do, this depends on the template engine you're using.

Now, how to choose to implement a filter or a model method? This depends on what you want.

If you want to titled a string, this is most likely to be a filter. Cause it's not related to a model but just a string. Plus your filter will be very reusable.

From now on, if you have to deal with function that are related to model, you should use model method.

Keep in mind that you can speed up your templates generation just by using [Jinja 2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/).